# Give more style to div reflection

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to add reflection to div using following css .

CSS ::

```
   div.reflection
{
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    opacity:0.6;
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
    top:82%;
    height:30%;
    width:100%; 

}
```

Reflection is coming but its just flip image with lower opacity value . how can i add more style to reflection ,i want  to give reflection as shown in below pic ..[image]

but with my css i am getting this ,
[image]

Comment: I think you're after a technique known as 3D transform. There are so many examples on the net, I wouldn't know where to start! Just search for `css 3d transform` with google images.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities to achieve that:

You can define an svg (or a gradient image) and mask the reflection image with that or even use the `mask-image property` and use a gradient to mask the image:

[This Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jDtWg/1/) shows both techniques. Webkit uses

```
div::after{
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1));
}
```

and Firefox the svg with the mask:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="0%" x2 ="0" y2="100%">
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="0"/>
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="mask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect y="0.3" width="1" height=".7" fill="url(#gradient)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>

div::after{
   mask: url(#mask);
}
```